# Firebase Button onClick, set UID child

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I have an problem with Firebase!, I've created register and login page and works fine!. but i have an problem. [why my button create a new 'child'?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcpD3.png)
How can i put button 'onClick' on same UID from identify users by button clicks ? [What I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQsW2.png), I don't know how firebase works 100% can anyone explain for me? i really need to {get} does click buttons for identify  every user on database. [My page button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEQIb.png)

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button influenciador;
private Button marca;

private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    influenciador = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BotaoSouInfluenciador);
    marca = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BotaoSouMarca);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuários");

    influenciador.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mDatabase.child("Usuários").push().setValue("Pizza");
            openDIContrato();
        }
    });

    marca.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mDatabase.child("Usuários").setValue("Burger");

            openMarcaContrato();
        }
    });
  }
public void openDIContrato() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DIContrato.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }

public void openMarcaContrato() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MarcaContrato.class);
    startActivity(intent);
 }
}
```

**Users class**

```
public class Usuarios {

private String id;
private String email;
private String aniversario;
private String senha;
private String nome;
private String sexo;

public Usuarios() {
}

public void salvar(){
    DatabaseReference referenciaFirebase = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase();
    referenciaFirebase.child("Usuários").child(String.valueOf(getId())).setValue(this);
}

@Exclude

public Map<String, Object> toMap(){
    HashMap<String, Object> hashMapUsuario = new HashMap<>();
    hashMapUsuario.put("id", getId());
    hashMapUsuario.put("email", getEmail());
    hashMapUsuario.put("aniversario", getAniversario());
    hashMapUsuario.put("nome", getnome());
    hashMapUsuario.put("sexo", getSexo());

    return hashMapUsuario;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

public String getnome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setnome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getAniversario() {
    return aniversario;
}

public void setAniversario(String aniversario) {
    this.aniversario = aniversario;
}

public String getSexo() {
    return sexo;
}

public void setSexo(String sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
 }
}
```

Comment: you can use FirebaseAuth class,  this class get the firebase authentication 
find the more information here, https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth hope it's help full

Comment: @PinhaDooido did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit I need to delete my reference? 'mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuários");' and put your code? your code 'ref.child(iD).child("Button").setValue("Pizza");' i need to put on onClick right?.

Comment: @PinhaDooido yes inside your `onClickListener()` just put this code instead of the line `mDatabase...`

Comment: And don't forget to initialise `iD` as the one in your database.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit Omg, it worked! thanks. but before i 'accept your answer' i need to know! i really need to put manually my ID for every user? LOL.

Comment: Yes, if you do it this way, you can skip putting `iD` by using `orderByChild()` query but you need to have `button` node in your database for that at all times.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit Oh, i got it!. I appreciate that, thanks bro </3(nohomo).

Comment: Glad to help, Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the correct reference to your database. From the image with title "what I want to do", you can do so with this piece of code:

```java
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Usuários");

ref.child(iD).child("Button").setValue("Pizza");

//id is the string I can see in the databse image dG9ue...
```